# Laravel eloquent: Combine belongsToMany Relation with hasOne Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

is there any chance to combine belongsTo relation with an hasOne relationship?

I have for example this tables:

```
    users
    id
    username

    events
    id
    name

    states
    id
    name

    event_user
    id
    event_id
    user_id
    state_id
```

In event model is this function which returns an belongsToMany Relation. But I need to get the State Relation too.

In event model is this function which returns an belongsToMany Relation. But I need to get the State Relation too.

Has anyone an idea?

LinuTuris

Comment: Can a user and event have different state ids?

Comment: You need 2 relations in event model. One for user and one for state. Both are one to many. BelongsToMany or hasMany.

Comment: @Coola yes an event and an User can have different state ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using Pivot:

```
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
 
class EventUser extends Pivot
{
  
    public function state(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }
}
```

Within User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function events(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class)->using(EventUser::class)->withPivot('state_id');;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$user = User::find($id);

foreach ($user->events as $event) {
   $state = $event->pivot->state;
}
```

Reference https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

**Another way** is using hasMany:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;     
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
     
class EventUser extends Model
{
  
    public function state(): BelongsTo
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }

    
    public function event(): BelongsTo
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }
}
```

In User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function eventUsers(): BelongsToMany
   {
      return $this->hasMany(EventUser::class);
   }
}
```

Then:

```
$user = User::with('eventUsers.event', 'eventUsers.state')->first();
```